how to add lookup to existing big list
I have a parent and child lists.
Job list has unique job (title) and Job History list with none unique job (title)
Both lists are already over 5000 items.
I need to report on the history but need one column from Job to show too. (related by job)
When I create a lookup column on history, I have no way to tell it to relate by the title column on both lists.
Do I need to write some PS1 to populate the lookup column?
Thank you

Yes, you will have to add values to lookup column in history list.
